# conditional linq query behavior

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a feeling the title is misleading, please edit if you choose to. when I do this:

```
var q  = (condition)?(from ...Select(..)): (from.. Select(..));
```

I get a error at ":" saying

```
Type of conditional expression could not be determined because 
there is no implicit conversion between anonymous types.
```

But if I do:

```
var b = some base linq query;
var q = (condition)?(use b here one way):(use b here differently);
```

no complaints. Why? How is second way different?

Edit:

Everywhere, my final projections are the same. (Final .Select(....) everywhere has same fields)

Edit2:

**I apologize.. typo on my part. Select()s everywhere were not the same. Method 1 works fine too if the projections 'match'**

Comment: Are you selecting the same thing in both cases? It would really help if you'd give us a short but *complete* example of the case that doesn't work.

Comment: Well if you put some actual values in `some base linq query` and `from ...Select(..))`, etc., people would be able to help. Otherwise it's all guesses. The error message clearly states that it can't see any implicit conversion between anonymous type returned by first select and the second select. In your last example, assuming you don't have different anonymous types in `use b here one way` and `use b here differently`, it doesn't give that error.

Comment: @JonSkeet I was just about to say that, it looks like your selects are *different*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It think the error message explains this:

> Type of conditional expression could not be determined because 
>   there is no implicit conversion between anonymous types.

This

```
var x = 0 < 2 ? new { a = 1 } : new { a = 2 }
```

would compile. but this

```
var x = 0 < 2 ? new { a = 1 } : new { b = 2 };
```

would give the error above because  `{a=1}` and `{b=2}` are not the same anonymous types.

Answer (score 2):

If you did a cast after your LINQ query everything would be fine.

Its sort of the same problem that you get then you do something like

```
int? val = true ? 1 : null;
```

That won't work, but if you cast the null like this:

```
int? val = true ? 1 : (int?)null;
```

It does.

Comment: This doesn't apply in my case. Apparently if both anonymous types returned in Select() match, all is well

Comment: @Brian Interesting, didn't know that!  Must have been writing the compiler code for handling that case, yikes.

Answer (score 2):

A conditional expression needs the two operands it's evaluating to be the same type.  So if you do

```
var a = (condition)? "A" : "B";
```

... both "A" and "B" are of the same type (string), so the result, `a`, will be of type `string`.

What your error message is telling you is that your two operands (the two `from ... Select` statements) evaluate to anonymous types, but not the same anonymous type, and it can't convert one anonymous type into another.  Thus it doesn't know what type the result, `q`, should be.

While I am not 100% sure, I believe that even if your two expressions are exactly the same, they will be different anonymous types. At any rate, the fact that you got that error indicates that they are not the same anonymous type.

With your second set of statements, you first set `b` to be equal to the result of a linq query.  Hence it has a type.  Although your statement does say so, the fact that the code compiles implies that `(use b here one way)` and `(use b here differently)` return results of the same type.  If they both return an instance of the same type as `b`, for example, they will be of the same type.

Comment: apparently as long as the anonymous types 'match' all is well

Comment: @AnnL, regarding *While I am not 100% sure, ...*, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696(v=vs.100).aspx) states that: `If two or more anonymous types in the same assembly have the same number and type of properties, in the same order, the compiler treats them as the same type. They share the same compiler-generated type information.`